# Self-citation question

Tags: citations, self-citation

Suppose there is a paper by author A and B. B alone later publishes another paper, citing the first paper. Does this count or not as a *self-citation* to author A?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define “self-citation”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95736/how-to-define-self-citation)

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes, indeed.

Comment: Actually, I think the cited question has an incorrect accepted answer. I think that, contrary to the comments there, people _do_ take it as a personal negative if it is frequently done. It is treated as a 'property' of authors, not just of papers. But author A has no part in this.